# Vue2 Tocuh Events Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event error when swiping

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova, nuxt.js, touchmove

I'm using the `vue2-touch-events` plugin to create some "native like" swiping behaviour for a Nuxt JS hybrid app built with Cordova. I've implemented an element (positioned absolutely) over the majority of the screen that once swiped on the `$router` pushes to a new page.

This has been working fine up until recently where I have noticed an error being fired in my console:

```
[Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
```

I'm not too sure why I'm experiencing this error, and have attempted to revert some things which has made no difference. The code in question is attached:

HTML Vue JS markup

```html
<span
  v-touch:swipe.right="swipePrevPage"
  v-touch:swipe.left="swipeNextPage"
  class="page-swipe-trigger">
</span>
```

Implemented methods

```js
/**
 * Handle page swipe (next page)
 */
swipePrevPage() {
  if (this.page && this.id && this.$refs.hasPages[0].innerText === 'true') {
    if (this.prevPage != -1) {
      this.$router.push('/url/' + this.page + '/' + this.prevPage)
    } else {
      this.$router.push('/url/' + this.page)
    }
  }
},


/**
 * Handle page swipe (next page)
 */
swipeNextPage() {
  if (this.page && this.id && this.$refs.hasPages[0].innerText === 'true') {
    if (this.nextPage < parseInt(this.$refs.getPages[0].innerText)) {
      this.$router.push('/url/' + this.page + '/' + this.nextPage)
    }
  }
}
```

For refernece, I'm using version [2.3.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-touch-events) of the plugin, and have it configured like this...

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vue2TouchEvents from 'vue2-touch-events'

Vue.use(Vue2TouchEvents, {
  touchClass: 'touched',
  swipeTolerance: 50
})
```

If someone could help me with why I'm experiencing this error, the error shows up when **trying to swipe.**